# Why is $E(nX)=nE(X)$?

Tags: probability

I know that this is correct for expected value, but then I don't know how it's possible.$$ E\ [n X]=n \sum_i x_i \times P_{X}(X = n x_i) $$ 
but $ P_{X}(X = n x_i) $ is not equal to $ P_X(X = x{_i}) $ which would make the equation as : $$ n \sum x_i\times P_X(X=x_i)$$ that is equal to $ \ \ n \ E[X] .$

PS_edit: some one told me it's because probability indices are not linear, what does it have to do with my question exactly?

Comment: What does $P_X{_i}(n x)$ mean on the right-hand side? I would have expected the right-hand side to say $P(X = x_i)$ where you have $P_X{_i}(n x)$.

Comment: @TannerSwett how about $ P(X = n \times x_i) $ ?

Comment: Is $P_{X_i}(nx)$ refers as probability mass function of $nX$ at the point $nx_i$? Notations are not understandable here...

Comment: I'm quite sure it means $\Pr(X=nx)$.

Comment: @parvin I don't see why you write $P_X(X=nx_i)$, when your rv is $nX$.

Comment: $E(nX)=\sum nx_iP_{nX}(nX=nx_i)=n\sum x_iP_X(X=x_i)=nE(X)$.

Comment: @MANMAID Why does your comment contain the same notational mistake as the OP, which is to use $$P_X(X=x)$$ instead of $$P(X=x)$$ or of $$P_X(\{x\})\ ?$$

Comment: @Did wrote that because OP used that notation. I don't know if he knows the notation $P(X=x)$ (Although I should have mentioned it, thanks).

Comment: @MANMAID "wrote that because OP used that notation" ?? What a bad approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,

$$E(g(X)) := \sum_j y_j \Pr(g(X)=y_j)$$

But in general, if $X$ is a discrete random variable and a function $g$ gives $g(X)$ also a discrete random variable, * then:

$$E(g(X)) = \sum_i g(x_i) \Pr(X=x_i)$$

Here $g(X) = cX$. You are correct that $\Pr(X=x)\ne \Pr(X=g(x))$ in general.

There is an analogous theorem for $X$ and $g(X)$ continuous RV's.

This theorem is known as the **Law of the Unconscious Statistician**. It's called so because statisticians sometimes use this law without even realizing they are invoking a theorem. Proofs can be found on this website.

Edit: here's a proof of the discrete case:

[Proving the Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415196/proving-the-law-of-the-unconscious-statistician)

Second edit: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Expectation_of_Function_of_Discrete_Random_Variable

- according to Did, $g(X)$ is always discrete if $X$ is discrete, which sounds reasonable

Comment: thank you I'll check that now

Comment: Your first definition is wrong (on several counts simultaneously) and should read $$E(g(X))=\sum_jy_jP(g(X)=y_j)$$ The rest of the post is also rather confused at times (for example, $g(X)$ is **always** discrete if $X$ is discrete) but this initial mistake really messes everything up.

Answer (score 3):

$$E(cX)=\sum_{x\in\Omega}cxP(X=x)=c\sum_{x\in\Omega}xP(X=x)=cE(x)$$

Comment: Is this what OP trying to say? I think he knows this.

Comment: @MANMAID OP is getting confused about writing $E(nX)$ as a summation.

Comment: so no changes to probability? what if we have E[X^2] ?

Comment: @parvin $E(X^2)=\sum x^2P(X=x)$

Comment: i see thank you @MANMAID

Comment: @MANMAID Yes, this is what OP is trying to say. I just wrote it out correctly. His original calculation had an error.