# Proving short cut for expected value of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions

In the case where you have some Random Variable Y=g(X) and you know the pdf of X.

In general the  expected value of Y is ... 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR26n.jpg)

However since Y is a function of X and we know the pdf of X we can say,

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCoqA.jpg)

so clearly, these two methods provide the same result, but can someone help me prove that the second formula is actual equal to E[Y]...?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/if32A.jpg)

My apologies for the lack of effort on this post, I only have a few more hours until my exam and I am trying to make sense of this. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is known as the "law of the unconscious statistician". You can try searching for that online. For example, there is some discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/415196/proving-the-law-of-the-unconscious-statistician/1622319).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just compare the density function within different integrations...

There are two ways we can compute the expectation of $Y=g(X)$, which are

$$E(Y))=\int_{y \in R(Y)} y f_y(y) dy$$

$$E(g(X)))=\int_{x\in R(X)} g(x) f_x(x) dx$$

Notice that the intergration is over different event space. When you want to compare the density function within integrations, you need to change the event space $y\in R(Y)$ and $dy$.

Notice that $R(Y) = \{y:y=g(x), x \in R(X)\}$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=g'(x)$, $x=g^{-1}(y)$, and given given the pdf of X, $f_x(x)$, we can rewrite the second integration

$$E(g(X)))=\int_{y=g(x), x \in R(X)} g(x) f_x(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{1}{g'(x)} dy$$

Now we have two integration over same sample space, and you can compare the density function, which is 
$$ f_y(y) = f_x(g^{-1}(y)) \frac{1}{g'(x)} $$

Done.