# Expectation of a transformation of a random variable, general case

Tags: probability, expected-value

X is a random variable with known CDF, $F(X)$. Let's define $Y = g(X)$. The expectation of $Y$ is

$\mathbb{E} [Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dF_X(x)$

I don't understand why the latter equation is true. Why isn't necessary to compute the distribution of $Y$ to compute the expectation? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician#Proof

Comment: But that proof is only for differentiable functions with monotonic inverse when that result can be proved for any real function $g(x)$

Comment: @TomKeen Did you see the measure-theoretic proof?

Comment: @r.e.s. i have seen two proof, the measure theoretic and the particular case for real functions.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1720763/16397