# Proof that given a continuous random variable $X$ with density function $f(x)$ then $\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x)dx$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have tried a million things and I just can't seem to crack this.

To repeat it the question is, given a continuous random variable $X$, with density function $f(x)$ prove that:
$$
\mathbb E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx
$$

I was able to prove it using going from $0$ to $\infty$ but I can't figure it out more generally.

**Edit:** Just to add more information, I have found the following to be true and I know that it will help with the proof:
$$
\mathbb E[g(X)] = \int_{0}^{\infty}P(g(X)>y)dy  - \int_{0}^{\infty}P(g(X)< -y)dy
$$

I have tried so many things but nothing works.

Comment: Have a look at the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.

Comment: You cannot prove that $E(g(X)) = \int g(x) f_X(x) dx$ in a "basic" way; you'd need measure theory. (You can prove it for some special $g$ such as increasing or decreasing.)

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1720763/38584